# Slow random sample generation without replacement in scipy

Tags: python, random, scipy, hashmap, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create sparse matrix representation of a random hash map h:[n] -> [t] which maps each i
     to exactly s random location of available d locations and the value at those location are drawn from some discrete distribution.

```
:param d: number of bins
:param n: number of items hashed
:param s: sparsity of each column
:param distribution: distribution object.
```

Here is my attempt:

```
start_time=time.time()
distribution = scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=([-1.0, +1.0  ], [0.5, 0.5]),name = 'dist')

data = (1.0/sqrt(self._s))*distribution.rvs(size=self._n*self._s)
col = numpy.empty(self._s*self._n)
for i in range(self._n):
  col[i*self._s:(i+1)*self._s]=i

row = numpy.empty(self._s*self._n)

print time.time()-start_time

for i in range(self._n):
  row[i*self._s:(i+1)*self._s]=numpy.random.choice(self._d, self._s, replace=False)

S = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix( (data, (row, col)), shape = (self._d,self._n))

print time.time()-start_time

return S
```

Now for creating this map for n=500000, s=10,d=1000, it is taking me around 20s on my decent workstation, in which 90% of time is consumed in generating row indices. Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Any alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
col = numpy.empty(self._s*self._n)
for i in range(self._n):
  col[i*self._s:(i+1)*self._s]=i
```

looks like something that could be written as one non-looping expression; though it probably isn't a big time consumer

My first guess is - but I need to play with this to be sure; I think it's assigning all rows the column index number.

```
col = np.empty(self._s, self._n)
col[:,:] = np.arange(self._n)
col = col.ravel()
```

Something similar for:

```
for i in range(self._n):
    row[i*self._s:(i+1)*self._s]=numpy.random.choice(self._d, self._s, replace=False)
```

is, I think, picking `_s` values from `_d` `_n` times.  Doing the no-replace along _s, but allowing replace on `_n` could be tricky.

Without running the code myself (with smaller `n`) I'm stumbling around a bit.  Which is the slow part, generating `col`, `row`, or the final `csr`?  Iteration on `n=500000` is going to be slow.

The matrix will be (1000, 500000), but with (10*500000) nonzero items.  So a sparsity of .01.  Just for comparison it would be interesting to generate a sparse random matrix of similar size and sparsity

```
In [5]: %timeit sparse.random(1000, 500000, .01)
1 loop, best of 3: 24.6 s per loop
```

and the dense random choices:

```
In [8]: timeit np.random.choice(1000,(10,500000)).shape
10 loops, best of 3: 53 ms per loop
In [9]: np.array([np.random.choice(1000,(10,)) for i in range(500000)]).shape
Out[9]: (500000, 10)
In [10]: timeit np.array([np.random.choice(1000,(10,)) for i in range(500000)]).
    ...: shape
1 loop, best of 3: 12.7 s per loop
```

So, yes, the large iteration loop is expensive.  But given the replacement policy there might not be a way around that.  Or is there?

So as first guess, creating `row` takes half the time, creating the sparse matrix the other half.  I'm not surprised.  You are using the `coo` style of input, which requires `lexsorting` and summing for duplicates when converting to `csr`.  We might be able to gain speed by using the `indptr` type of input.  There won't be duplicates to sum.  And since there are consistently 10 nonzero terms per row, generating the `indptr` values won't be hard.  But I can't do that off the top of my head. (oops, that's the transpose).

`random` sparse to `csr` is just a bit slower:

```
In [11]: %timeit sparse.random(1000, 500000, .01, 'csr')
1 loop, best of 3: 28.3 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes generating row indices is taking 90% time. Do you think of some other alternatives which can help with this? I mean this is too slow for my purpose.